# Why is number of in_channels in downsample Conv2d different from num_channels in bn2, shouldn't they be same?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, resnet

The value in num_channels in bn2 and in_channels in Conv2d in downsample should be the same because the number of channels do not change at this point, so how come in resnet18 architecture they have different values.

[image]

Generally what happens is the in_channels is equal to out_channels of the previous channel.

##### Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of channels is different because you're looking at a skip connection.

You can't see it by printing your model (I'm assuming it's ResNet18 from Torchvision), but if you look up the implementation of the `BasicBlock` class that you've printed, it's the following:

```
    def forward(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        identity = x

        out = self.conv1(x)
        out = self.bn1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)

        out = self.conv2(out)
        out = self.bn2(out)

        if self.downsample is not None:
            identity = self.downsample(x)

        out += identity
        out = self.relu(out)

        return out
```

In your case, `downsample` is not `None`. `downsample` takes as input **the same `x` tensor** the provided to the `forward` method, so the number of input channels must match the number of input channels that `conv1` has, since `conv1` acts on the same tensor.

The output of `downsample` gets added to the output of `bn2`, so the number of output channels of `downsample` needs to match the number of output channels of `bn2`. Looking at the print you provided, you can see that does.